# PHP -> simplexml_load_file skip to next when error

Tags: php

I have searched a lot for the answer for my question, so I hope you guys can help me :)

My php file is loading a XML file, and work through every tag like this:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($filedir) or die("Error: Cannot create object"); 
foreach($xml->children() as $books) {
}
```

My issue is, that sometimes the XML's one tag (out of 100) missing an ending or has a error.

When a error occurs I want the foreach to stop and continue to the next one.

If error = take next foreach

If correct = run the foreach

Do you have a solution on that? :)

Thank you!

Comment: By definition, XMLs must be well-formed, so missing tag invalidates it. Consider checking source of XML generation before continuing further.